# running gcc failed: exit status 1 in golang in windows

Tags: windows, go, gcc

when i run my code fyne package GUI in golang , i get this error in terminal:
C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-594045439\go.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
please can help me to solve this issue.

```
 gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-cxx-flags=-DWINPTHREAD_STATIC --disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-threads --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-gnu-ld --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-pkgversion=tdm64-1 --with-bugurl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)
```

Comment: Hi @isra, please format your questions properly for a better understanding for all of us here. Also, we could help you more if you would've shared a sample code for us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally I solved it by installing an older version of gcc.

my go version is 1.19.4 and my gcc version is 12.2 when i had the problem, so i reinstall gcc 11.4, then I recompiled once and successfully solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This most commonly occurs when you have build tools for different architectures, such as 64bit Go tools but 32bit C compiler. If you can’t solve this please add the details of your tools and how they were installed.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I uesd  64 bit GO tools

Comment: gcc -v   -->gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)